# Make a Unit Test in for-if statement Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular-test

I have this code in my component. I try to get detail of a category based on id. I already have the id from the start, so I just need to find the rest detail of it.

```
export class editCategoryComponent implements onInit {
    const id='ABC'
    let name='';
    let category: Category[]=[];
    
    constructor(catService: CategoryService)

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // code to get category, done
        this.catService.getCategory().subscribe((data) => {
            this.category = data;
        });

        // code to get detail of certain category
        for(let i=0; i<this.category.length; i++) {
          if(id === this.category[i].category_id) {
              name=category[i].name;
              break
          }
        }
    }
}
```

My unit test is like this. I set the id in the component, and also set the category from a mock that I created. It's just an array of category object.

```
mockCategory = [
    {
        category_id: 'ABC',
        category_name: 'lorem ipsum'
    },
    {
        category_id: '123',
        category_name: 'lorem-ipsum'
    },
]
describe('editCategoryComponent', () => {
    let component: editCategoryComponent
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<EditComponent>
    let service: CategoryService

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditCategoryComponent)
        component = fixture.componentInstance
        service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(CategoryService)
    })

    it('should get detail category and success', () => {
        spyOn(service, 'getCategory).and.returnValue(of(mockCategory));
        fixture.detechChanges();
        component.id = 'ABC';
        
        component.category.forEach((key), => {
            if(key.category_id === component.id) {
                fixture.detectChanges();
                expect(component.name).toEqual(key.category_name);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Up to foreach, my test already detect that component.category is not null, I thought it should be able to get data from it. But I get an error expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality. It said that Expected: "Text", Received: "", and I also look for the coverage and it only cover up to the if statement. The statement goes "name=..." and so on is not covered. So how do I make the unit test to cover after if statement?

I already make id in component exist in category, so it should be proceed to if. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a complete code of the component

Comment: i've provided complete code of component

Comment: @vjchrisintha 
Not sure what this part is doing, // code to get category, done
You are getting some service from the injector that was not used. Are you sure it will not initialize the category array somewhere.
P.S. 
you don't need to run detectChanges for every category then. 
Try to move it above the foreach. 
I'll leave the answer, because is partially useful.

Comment: actually i did the category in unit test by using spy, so i spy the service and return value of(mockCategory). i thought it doesn't really matter since i checked it on console and my array is filled. i'll change it then.

Answer (score 0):

That block of code you expect to be ran after **detectchanges**() wasn't executed probably.
So after you are not giving us the complete code there, I'll assume you probably use some
of the hooks, ngOnChanges  or ngOnInit.
There is two possible scenarios here.

1. You are using **ngOnInit**.

- For **ngOnInit** to be called you need to use
  **TestBed.createComponent()**
- You can call the function manually **component.ngOnInit()**.

2. You are using **ngOnChange**

- You can call **ngOnChange** manually
- You can wrap your component in a new test component and test the result there. [Check this article](http://%20https://medium.com/@christophkrautz/testing-ngonchanges-in-angular-components-bbb3b4650ee8).

Comment: i've provided complete unit test, and also i've tried to call the function manually component.ngOnInit but the result is just the same